# Is there a way to right-justify a main title of a base (hist) plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to get the title of a plot to align to the right-most part of the plot.

To clarify, in the example to follow, the title of the plot is aligned to the center.

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(2, 2))
hist(islands)
utils::str(hist(islands, col="gray", labels = TRUE))
```

Comment: That's the one! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use separate function for the main title and graphical parameter adj:

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(2, 2))
hist(islands,main=NULL)
title("Histogram of islands",adj=1)
utils::str(hist(islands, col="gray", labels = TRUE,main=NULL))
title("Histogram of islands",adj=1)
```

Comment: Ok, but not necessary: hist(islands,  adj=1). But it's documented unter "title".

Comment: @DieterMenne That will also justify the axis labels.